# Finding the position of a point on the line

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

Let us suppose we have a line $l_1 = ax + by + c = 0$ and we have a point P,  $P(x_p, y_p)$ that is outside of this line. If we draw a perpendicular line from point $P$ to a point on the $l_1$. What would be the coordinates of this point ? I know there are many ways to do it. But I am looking for a single equation that can describe this point ($Q$) ?

[image]

Comment: You can compute the equation of a line which is perpendicular to the given one.

Comment: Please edit the question to tell us what  you mean by a "single equation", and tell us why one of the "many ways" to find that point don't satisfy you.

Comment: I am trying to write a code and I need this information. Othwerise its possible to solve but I was curious about that is there way to describe the point Q by single equation

Comment: Simple things should be preferably kept simple. Plug in $ P(x_p,y_p)$ into $b x+a y +k=0 $, to find $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q(x,y).$

Thus, since $PQ$ is perpendicular to our line $x$ and $y$ are solutions of the following system:
$$ax+by+c=0$$ and $$bx-ay-bx_p+ay_p=0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $$Q\left(\frac{b^2x_p-aby_p-ac}{a^2+b^2},\frac{a^2y_p-abx_p-bc}{a^2+b^2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer